# Use of Unit Test in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, xctest

I am writing my first bigger iOS project and I want to use as much of Xcode 5 as possible. Now I want to use testing but I have never done it before.

My project uses come `Views` and dynamic `TableViews. How could I implement the test in the code, so that it makes sense?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please start by watching WWDC '13 session [409 - Testing in Xcode 5](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/). It's a very good starting point.

Next, if you're not feeling confident of your approach to unit testing, I'd recommend reading ["Test-Driven iOS Development"](http://www.informit.com/store/test-driven-ios-development-9780321774187) by [Graham Lee](https://twitter.com/secboffin).

For now, remember that a *unit test* tests single "unit" of functionality and does not cover performance, UI interaction and whole system integration.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll check it out.

Comment: In addition some generic books and articles on Unit testing should help getting you into the basics - Unit Testing has been around a long, long time after all ;-)

Comment: This book appears to be about Xcode 4.   Anything around that deals with unit testing on Xcode 5?

Comment: @Gallymon: did you check the WWDC video?

Comment: @matm:  Yes, I did, thanks.  Also had a look at another video by a fellow named Penn of Rubber City Software given at a Cocoa Slopes gathering in Provo, Utah recently.  And I looked at an e-Book: "iOS 7 Programming Fundamentals" by Neuburg which had a brief but clear explanation.  So, I was able to setup my testing stuff quite easily after all that.  Cheers.